# How to get correct cumulative balance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have this simple query

```
select ArticleID, Prix, Qte, InfStock
    , SUM(Qte*InfStock) OVER (Partition BY ArticleID ORDER BY DateDocument) AS CUMUL
FROM Balance
```

Please look the result (Line 4)
[Here is the backup file(zipped)](http://www.over-b.com/v-7.1.3/db_balance.zip)

[image]

Comment: Please don't use images for data, use formatted text. And if you post your sample data as DDL+DML people can assist you much easier.

Comment: No, in my mind, is it bug, i have just Sql express 2014 SP1, is database file corrupted?, the entire result is about 501K row.

Comment: You would need to show us InfStock and DateDocument so we can see what the issue supposedly is. Possibly you have ties for the date column in which case you need to know the default is RANGE not ROWS

Comment: To troubleshoot, include `DateDocument` in the select list and add `ORDER BY ArticleID, DataeDocument` at the end of the query.

Comment: @saimmm0710 highly unlikely its a bug, but thats why you need to include a [mre] with sample data.

Comment: InfStock is the influence of the stock that take 1,0 or -1, DateDocument  is datetime col,

Comment: I didn't notice that `InfStock` is shown to us. The values where it all has `198` will all have the same value for `DateDocument`. This is how ties are treated with `SUM() OVER` unless you specify `ROWS`

Comment: i am working! to share just the table

Comment: You also need to order the query by `DateDocument` to ensure your running balance is in the same order as the records listed.

Comment: @saimmm0710 we don't want your backup file, we want a [mre] with the emphasis on *minimal*. Besides I think you have enough in the answers and comments provided to solve the issue.

Comment: I have added the link to download the backup file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add to the end of the `OVER` clause `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`.

`SUM` defaults to `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING` which can cause issues like this.

See [here](https://www.sqlpassion.at/archive/2015/01/22/sql-server-windowing-functions-rows-vs-range/) for example, for further explanation.

Comment: and/or add a tie breaker to `ORDER BY` so it is always unique/determinsitic

Comment: Non-determinism is a separate issue. It may return different results each time, but each result is fundamentally correct. Without `ROWS` the result is just wrong *EDIT* Yes you can get around this with determinism but that's effectively just a hack.

Comment: It is not a separate issue - the difference in results between `RANGE` and `ROWS` comes into play when there are ties in the `ORDER BY` clause. So if the ties are not possible they will behave the same (results wise). There are still performance benefit of specifying  `ROWS`  in some cases though (in 2014 it will always be better performance to use `ROWS`)

Comment: Also need to "You also need to order the query by DateDocument to ensure the running balance is in the same order as the records listed." right?

Comment: @DaleK Not necessarily. The results would be correct for each row. The ordering of the final result is not necessary except for display purposes.

Comment: @Charlieface well exactly, but if OP is using that for a visual guide the balances won't show in the correct order which could lead to confusion.

Comment: select ArticleID,Prix,Qte,InfStock, 
SUM(Qte*InfStock) OVER (Partition BY ArticleID  ORDER BY DateDocument  ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)  FROM Balance Worked fine

Comment: @saimmm0710 `AND CURRENT ROW ` is default anyway so you can just write `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`