# How can I select records from the last value accumulated

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the next data: TABLE_A

| RegisteredDate | Quantity |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 13:00 | 100 |
| 2022-03-01 13:10 | 20 |
| 2022-03-01 13:20 | -80 |
| 2022-03-01 13:30 | -40 |
| 2022-03-02 09:00 | 10 |
| 2022-03-02 22:00 | -5 |
| 2022-03-03 02:00 | -5 |
| 2022-03-03 03:00 | 25 |
| 2022-03-03 03:20 | -10 |

If I add cumulative column

```
select RegisteredDate, Quantity
    , sum(Quantity) over ( order by RegisteredDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Summary
from TABLE_A
```

| RegisteredDate | Quantity | Summary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 13:00 | 100 | 100 |
| 2022-03-01 13:10 | 20 | 120 |
| 2022-03-01 13:20 | -80 | 40 |
| 2022-03-01 13:30 | -40 | **0** |
| 2022-03-02 09:00 | 10 | 10 |
| 2022-03-02 22:00 | -5 | 5 |
| 2022-03-03 02:00 | -5 | **0** |
| 2022-03-03 03:00 | 25 | 25 |
| 2022-03-03 03:20 | -10 | 15 |

Is there a way to get the following result with a query?

| RegisteredDate | Quantity | Summary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-03 03:00 | 25 | 25 |
| 2022-03-03 03:20 | -10 | 15 |

This result is the last records after the last zero.

EDIT:

Really for the solution to this problem I need the: 2022-03-03 03:00 is the first date of the last records after the last zero.

[image: The expected result]

Comment: Is RegisteredDate unique in TABLE_A? If not, then you shouldn't rely on order by RegisteredDate, as an output may be different.

Comment: Hi @AntonGrig , RegisteredDate can repeat in the table

Comment: Is it appropriate for the task condition to add another one "Quantity" column to the order by clause?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `SUM` aggregate window function to calculation `grp` column which part represent to last value accumulated.

**Query 1**:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT RegisteredDate, 
        Quantity, 
        sum(Quantity) over (order by RegisteredDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Summary
    FROM TABLE_A
), cte2 AS (
   SELECT *,
          SUM(CASE WHEN Summary = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER(order by RegisteredDate desc) grp
   FROM  cte
)
SELECT RegisteredDate,
       Quantity
FROM cte2
WHERE grp = 0
ORDER BY RegisteredDate
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/35a81/3/0)**:

```
|       RegisteredDate | Quantity |
|----------------------|----------|
| 2022-03-03T03:00:00Z |       25 |
| 2022-03-03T03:20:00Z |      -10 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a CTE that returns the `summary` column and `NOT EXISTS` to filter out the rows that you don't need:

```
WITH cte AS (SELECT *, SUM(Quantity) OVER (ORDER BY RegisteredDate) Summary FROM TABLE_A)
SELECT c1.*
FROM cte c1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM cte c2 WHERE c2.RegisteredDate >= c1.RegisteredDate AND c2.Summary = 0 
  )
ORDER BY c1.RegisteredDate;
```

There is no need for `ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` in the `OVER` clause of the window function, because this is the default behavior.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=69fee30bf4681e7aa1838d41e2747457).

Comment: It is absolutely *not* the default behaviour. The default is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` which is subtly different, and slower

Comment: @Charlieface can you spot this *subtle* difference in these 3 queries: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b8c9777ed968da9e69550c6c4c463dfc?

Comment: No but I can spot in this one https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=09d20ec73f58974b52d31670e7750202. The difference shows up when the ordering column has duplicates, and the performance issue is because it uses a worktable instead of memory, in order to verify whether there are duplicates

Comment: @Charlieface *when the ordering column has duplicates* is not the case here. The order of the rows is defined uniquely by RegisteredDate so there is no need for ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW.

Comment: The fact that the sample set of sample data doesn't have it is no reason to not code defensively, especially [given the performance advantage](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/t-sql-window-functions-and-performance/). I have come across quite a few cases of wrong results https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70195704 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65972858 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68493814. You can even shorten it to just `ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, the `AND CURRENT ROW` I agree is not necessary

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
with u as
(select RegisteredDate, 
Quantity, 
sum(Quantity) over (order by RegisteredDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) as Summary
from TABLE_A)
select * from u
where RegisteredDate >= all(select RegisteredDate from u where Summary = 0)
and Summary <> 0;
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=91c125cf0be3a4cba6793d91abea3a95)

Basically what you want is for `RegisteredDate` to be >= `all` `RegisteredDates`s where `Summary = 0`, and you want `Summary <> 0`.

Answer (score 0):

When using window functions, it is necessary to take into account that RegisteredDate column is not unique in TABLE_A, so ordering only by RegisteredDate column is not enough to get a stable result on the same dataset.

```
With A As (
Select ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order by RegisteredDate, Quantity) As ID, RegisteredDate, Quantity       
From TABLE_A),
B As (
Select A.*, SUM(Quantity) Over (Order by ID) As Summary
From A)
Select Top 1 * 
From B
Where ID > (Select MAX(ID) From B Where Summary=0)
```

| ID | RegisteredDate | Quantity | Summary |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 2022-03-03 03:00 | 25 | 25 |